# How to efficiently display custom video stream in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, video, video-streaming, textures, codec

I have a custom library that can decode to RGBA or any other format.
What is the best way to marry it with OpenGL to decode onto texture so that it won't drop frames ?

Or is there a better way completely skipping textures?

**Edit:** 
Full HD video streamed over net. So performance is an issue. 30 Hz. Recorded.

Comment: What kind of resolution?  ~24Hz video, or ~60Hz?  Live, or recorded?

Comment: What kind of machine spec are you shooting for?  Atom laptop with an Intel GMA 950, or desktop-class processor with discrete AMD/NVidia  video card?

Answer (score 3):

[`glTexSubImage2D()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml) is quick and easy.  You may be able to get more throughput with a [PBO-based pipeline](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html#unpack), at the expense of more latency.

Looks like [glover](http://code.google.com/p/glover/) may have some example code, as well as Ye Olde [NeHe #35](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=35).

Comment: Thanks, I will look through links you provided. I also updated the question.

Comment: The link to `glTexSubImage2D()` is no longer valid. http://docs.gl/gl2/glTexSubImage2D is probably a good alternative.